# Backgammon variant — two player double or nothing on random walk?

Tags: probability, game-theory, conditional-expectation, expected-value

> Two players, A and B, play the following backgammon variant.
>
> A series of steps is labelled $-2$, $-1$, $0$, $1$ and $2$, and a
>   chess piece is placed on step $0$. A fair coin is flipped, and it
>   lands on heads, the chess piece is moved forward by one step, while if
>   it lands on tails, the piece is moved back by one step. Player A wins
>   if the piece lands on step $2$ first, while player B wins if the piece
>   lands on step $-2$ first, and the loser must pay the winner some
>   amount of money.
>
> The amount is originally set at \$1. Initially, either player can
>   challenge the other player to double this stake at any time (before
>   the game ends), and the other player must either accept this or
>   forfeit and lose the game. Following that, two consecutive challenges
>   cannot be raised by the same player (i.e. if player A challenges first
>   and B accepts, A cannot challenge again until B challenges him), and
>   only one challenge can be raised each turn.
>
> When should you challenge, and if challenged, should you accept? What
>   is the expected value of your strategy?

My initial thought was that if challenged, I would only accept when at $0$ (indifferent) and $+1$ (if I was player A) or $-1$ (if I was player B). However, this would mean that the other player challenged one step before possibly losing. How do I reconcile this? Is there a reason why a player would challenge if one step away from potentially losing?

Comment: For the continuous version of this game, [Keeler & Spencer](https://bkgm.com/articles/KeelerSpencer/OptimalDoublingInBackgammon/) worked out that you should double when you have an 80% chance of winning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analysis in quarague’s answer isn’t correct because it only takes the possibility of doubling once into account, whereas future doubling opportunities in fact increase the expected payoff.

Denote by $x_k$ the expected value of the game for $A$ when $A$ has score $k$ and has the right to challenge and $B$ doesn’t. We can guess that $A$ challenges when the score is $1$, and $B$ accepts, and then check whether this is self-consistent. Under these assumptions, we have

$$
2x_0=x_{-1}+x_1=x_{-1}-2x_{-1}=-x_{-1}
$$

and

$$
2x_{-1}=x_0+x_{-2}=x_0-1\;,
$$

and thus $x_{-1}=-\frac25$, $x_0=\frac15$ and $x_1=\frac45$. The assumptions turn out to be self-consistent, since the expected return for $A$ at score $1$ would only be $\frac12\left(\frac15+1\right)=\frac35\lt\frac45$ without challenging, and the expected return for $B$ upon refusing would be $-1\lt-\frac45$.

It remains to find the optimal strategy and expected return in the initial state of the game, where both players have the right to challenge. Denote these expected returns by $y_k$. Then $y_0=0$ by symmetry, and $y_1$ is $\frac12$ if $A$ doesn’t challenge, $1$ if $A$ challenges and $B$ refuses and $-2x_{-1}=\frac45$ if $A$ challenges and $B$ accepts, so $A$ challenges at score $1$ and $B$ accepts.

To summarize, the initial value of the game is $0$ by symmetry; a player challenges exactly if they have a score of $1$, the other player always accepts, and the value of the game for the player with the right to challenge is $-\frac25$, $\frac15$ and $\frac45$ at a score of $-1$, $0$ and $1$, respectively.

Answer (score -1):

One can analyse the expected values at each stage. First the base case without doubling, at stage 0, player A has an expected return of $0\$$ due to symmetry. At stage $1$, he has a $50\%$ chance to win immediately and a $50\%$ chance to go back to stage $0$. This gives A an expected return of $0.5\$$. By symmetry at stage $-1$ A has an expected return of $-0.5\$$.

Now for doubling, by symmetry only consider whether A should offer and whether B should accept. At stage 0, A has zero expected return, so doubling doesn't change anything, neither does it for B. At stage 1, if A offers to double and B accepts, A's expected return doubles, if B refuses it also doubles to the current stake. So A should offer to double and B can take the double or not but it doesn't change his expected return. At stage -1, if A offers to double and B accepts, A's expected return goes from $-0.5$ to $-1$, if B refuses it goes to $1$. So B would accept it but A shouldn't offer it.

Comment: This doesn't take future doubling opportunities into account; see my answer.